# Georeferenced image not displaying in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm still on my 'L' plates. I'm trying to georeference a map in QGIS so that I can trace out several features. I've done this (once) before, and don't understand why it wont work now.

I've a pdf map, that I've converted to tiff and jpg. They all load into the georeferencer. I've got 20 or so good control points spread across the map
I've set the projection to the same as my training file. The georeferencer will run, creates a new image file and loads this into QGIS. QGIS will not display the image.

The image is legit, and graphics software will display it.
QGIS will not display the new layer - even though the layer is loaded.
'Zoom to layer extent' shows a blank, white display.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the georeferenced image as it appears in the graphic software? What CRS dp you use and what extent are you working on? Can you share the file of the georeferenced image?

Comment: _"Still on my L plates" ? is it a brit expression ? lol .._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the CRS after all. I was using a Bing map tile - that was not set to the project CRS.